# Xamarin forms android: Old notifications are replaced by new notifications in foreground mode

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.android

I have implemented push notification on xamarin forms android project using FCM. **But when receive a new notification, old notifications are replaced by the new one. This is happening only when the app is in the foreground mode(when app is in open state).** No such issues in background state or killed state. Multiple notifications are showing in background state and killed state.

Following is my notification payload, where `webContentList` is my message data.

```
{
 "to" : "dmtfiSvBBM0:APA91bFnHkamMSYgxPuiSfdvKnU8hD_mOqrWijnENNgXVSkSgo1ILH3-uKVCU7Ez2PXXOhtDoobIyKBf5UshVfTmvjSqHgXMRTsqguKCSTjIfGnXrVP-_cNFq2sisshZO-BcfkwKTl-I",
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "notification" : {
      "body" : "This is body",
     "title": "Tech Team",
     "priority":"high",
     "content_available":true
 },
 "data" : {
    "webContentList": [
        {
            "webContentDefinitionId": 818084,
            "pageTitle": "CCD Grade 3-4",
            "pageKwd": "CCD Grade 3-4",
            "pageDesc": "CCD Grade 3-4",
            "siteId": 45,
            "pageCreatedTime": 1555145959428,
            "pageUpdatedDate": 1555927274279,
            "modifier": {
                "userId": 12944,
                "applicationId": 32,
                "username": "robert.downey",
                "email": "robert@master-mail.net",
                "firstName": "Robert",
                "lastName": "Downey"
            },
            "creator": {
                "userId": 12944,
                "applicationId": 32,
                "username": "robert.downey",
                "email": "robert@master-mail.net",
                "firstName": "Robert",
                "lastName": "Downey"
            }
        }
        ]
 },
  "ttl": 3600
}
```

I removed the `collapse_key` from the payload, but notifications are replacing in foreground mode.

Please suggest a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you handle the foreground notification creation by yourself?
If so, a classic mistake is to pass the same id over and over again when creating the local notification, for example like this

```
mNotificationManager.Notify(1, mBuilder.Build());
```

You need to pass a different ID for each notification

```
mNotificationManager.Notify(new Random().Next(),mBuilder.Build());
```